# Сохранение введенных данных

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Я хочу узнать, можно ли на JavaScipt написать такой код, чтобы он сохранял введённые данные в форму инпут, текстареа и т.д. в базу данных MySQL и в то же время в текстовый документ в формате Word, Excel на сервер.

Comment: Причем тут "кодировка" и тем более "кодировка в AJAX" - не могу понять.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript - это клиент, поэтому напрямую он не может сделать то что вы хотите.
В данном случае вам нада строить приложение использую JS (клиент), Сервер(к примеру на php, asp) и СУБД (MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

Неа, javascript может только менять содержимое в браузере - удалять поля, передвигать, скроллить страницу и другие мелочи)